# Serialize Netbios struct to send over TCP/IP in C, possible?

Tags: c, serialization, struct, netbios

I have 2 machines talking to each other using NetBIOS via NetBEUI. I am in the process of replacing NETBEUI with TCP. I am looking for the easiest and fastest way to do it. There is NetBios over TCP/IP protocol available but for some reason it's not working... I could not figure out why. So now, I am thinking to serialize the NetBIOS struct and send it over to another machine using TCP and de-serialize there. The struct look like below. Will serialize approach work?

```
typedef struct _NCB {
    UCHAR   ncb_command;            /* command code                   */
    UCHAR   ncb_retcode;            /* return code                    */
    UCHAR   ncb_lsn;                /* local session number           */
    UCHAR   ncb_num;                /* number of our network name     */
    PUCHAR  ncb_buffer;             /* address of message buffer      */
    WORD    ncb_length;             /* size of message buffer         */
    UCHAR   ncb_callname[NCBNAMSZ]; /* blank-padded name of remote    */
    UCHAR   ncb_name[NCBNAMSZ];     /* our blank-padded netname       */
    UCHAR   ncb_rto;                /* rcv timeout/retry count        */
    UCHAR   ncb_sto;                /* send timeout/sys timeout       */
    void (CALLBACK *ncb_post)( struct _NCB * );
    UCHAR   ncb_lana_num;           /* lana (adapter) number          */
    UCHAR   ncb_cmd_cplt;           /* 0xff => commmand pending       */
#ifdef _WIN64
    UCHAR   ncb_reserve[18];        /* reserved, used by BIOS         */
#else
    UCHAR   ncb_reserve[10];        /* reserved, used by BIOS         */
#endif
    HANDLE  ncb_event;              /* HANDLE to Win32 event which    */
                                /* will be set to the signalled   */
                                /* state when an ASYNCH command   */
                                /* completes                      */
} NCB, *PNCB;
```